# Installing php7 on Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) from official tar.gz file downloaded at php.net

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, apache2.4

I am new to the stackoverflow community and linux server administration.
I am running a Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) LTS server edition.

I have *Apache 2.4.7* installed and my current PHP version is *PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 (cli)*.

I want to upgrade my server to the latest version of PHP7 (currently 7.0.0).
Therefore I have downloaded the tar.gz file from the official php.net download site (https://www.php.net/downloads.php).

Due to the fact that I am a bloody beginner, the problem starts right after this step. I have googled a lot to find a answer how to simply install newer version of php on a running system. Most of the answers were related to the ppa of *Ondřej Surý* ([https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php-7.0](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php-7.0)) but I've read about people complaing about useing unsigned ppa archives in live systems.

So my question is: Could anybody please explain me the manual installation process of php7? And how to configure apache2.x running php5.5.x and php7 parallel?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Before you start compiling PHP and Apache yourself, use a ppa for this.

Comment: If you still want to compile it yourself (I would recommend it much less than using a ppa) the installation is described in great detail in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.php

Comment: @GeraldSchneider if I install php7 through the mentioned ppa, will it be linked to apache automatically ? can't find informations to this topic. Thank you for linking the php.net installation guide I will read it right asap.

Comment: How is your Apache connecting to PHP? Over `mod_php` or is it via FastCGI protocol? If it's over `mod_php` then I'm afraid you're screwed..

Comment: @Mjh my phpinfo() says that the server api is apache 2.0 so i think it uses the mod_php?

Comment: Ideal scenario for you is to run `php-fpm` for both `5.6` and `7.0` version. Different listening port should allow for trivial swapping between two versions. You're also using Linux, so there are no issues, using `mod_php` is significantly slower anyway and Apache is able to "speak" fastcgi protocol.

Comment: @Mjh Thank you for your comment. I will test some configurations on a test system.